# Как запустить скрипт java в браузере?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomcat

Заказчик попросил на сервере развернуть архив с файлами .jsp.
Есть куча файлов .jsp и папка, в которой есть .xml файл с вызовом servlet:

```xml
<servlet> <!--This servlet element is autogenerated-->
    <servlet-name>application_launcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.openwaygroup.application.servlet.ServletApplicationFactory</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Подскажите, какое ПО мне еще нужно установить на сервер (Apache Tomcat стоит) и какие действия произвести, чтобы получить страницу в браузере?

Comment: Надо собрать приложение и задеплоить в tomcat

Comment: такие вопросы с кондачка не решаются ;)
а если серьезно, то очень мало входных данных для конкретного ответа: какой версии сервер? какая конфигурация и режим работы (можно ли его перегружать)? в каком формате архив - war, jar, zip? для общей информации читайте матчасть https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/deployer-howto.html